# obtain Error: guru/nidi/graphviz/engine/Format when I try to use Schemacrawler

Tags: database, postgresql, schemacrawler

I try to use SchemaCrawler to generate an image of a database schema. A database I made in postgresql. But when i run the command, I have Error: guru/nidi/graphviz/engine/Format

I do not find any information about this error.

Comment: What is the SchemaCrawler command that you used? Please install Graphviz on your computer for a more complete set of formats.

Answer (score 0):

This error pops up because graphviz is not installed or properly configured on your system.
So, please try again by reinstalling Graphviz and familiarizing yourself with the configuration.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).